# Hibernate Mapping Issue Tomcat8

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat8

I'm having problem with mapping in hibernate and tomcat 8.

When I deploy the application(through manager/html or creating a new folder and putting the whole project) there is not problem but if I try to put the classes into WEB-INF of another existing application and run it, log says:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Telefonos is not mapped [FROM Telefonos where canal = :canal and (fechaTomado is null or (fechaTomado + 90) >= getdate())]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
at operaciones.telefonoscvts.ManejadorTelefonos.listTelefonos(ManejadorTelefonos.java:133)
at org.apache.jsp.comercial.comercial.ajax.traeNumero_jsp._jspService(traeNumero_jsp.java:123)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Telefonos is not mapped
```

Teléfonos entity

```
package operaciones.telefonoscvts.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "telefonos_cvts")
public class Telefonos implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "telefono")
private String telefono;

@Column(name = "modalidad")
private String modalidad;

@Column(name = "canal")
private String canal;

@Column(name = "fechaCarga")
private String fechaCarga;

@Column(name = "fechaTomado")
private String fechaTomado;

public Telefonos() {
}

//get and set methods
```

I tried many ways to make work it, the packages are fine, hibernate.cfg.xml it's read, I don't know why the app it's losing its mappings. Anny help is appreciated.

Hibernate: 4.3

Thanks!!

Comment: Show us the mapping of the Telefonos entity

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, updated!

Comment: *but if I try to put the classes into WEB-INF of another existing application and run it*, but how are you doing this exactly? show us the project hierarchy.

Comment: can u post your hibernate.cfg.xml???

Comment: The problem was fixed, I just changed the directory and it worked, I think that was a library problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your mapping is correct. The most probable solution is to check whether you have included the entity to Hibernate configuration:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    lsfb.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
    lsfb.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { 
        "operaciones.telefonoscvts.dao"
    });
    lsfb.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

The same effect you can achieve using xml based configuration. However I find annotations better in this case.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>operaciones.telefonoscvts.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>       
</bean>
```

Source: [Websystique](http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/)

Moreover, I recommend you to more the file `Telefonos.java` to the package `operaciones.telefonoscvts.entity` (or `model`) separately from the classes responsible to communication with database.